# how to use MethodAuthorizer in Restlet?

Tags: authorization, restlet

I'm currently working on a project with Restlet API.
Now, my router routes 6 different URI's to 6 different Resources.
What i want to do is only to restrict DELETE and PUT methods in 2 of my resources to only authorized users. 
I couldn't find any example or tutorial that i can learn about MethodAuthorizer. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the MethodAuthorizer the same way we can use the RoleAuthorizer (explained [here](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/27-restlet/46-restlet.html) - see the sample code at bottom of the page)

```
Router router = new Router(getContext());
router.attach("/your/path", YourResource.class);    
MethodAuthorizer ma = new MethodAuthorizer();
ma.getAnonymousMethods().add(Method.GET); // your allowed method for all user
ma.getAuthenticatedMethods().add(Method.DELETE); // your allowed method to authenticated user
ma.setNext(route);

rootRouter.attach("/admin", ma);
```

But it doesn't seem that it is the way to go :(
However if you take a look at the [workflow](http://wiki.restlet.org/developers/220-restlet/version/default/part/ImageData/data/Restlet%20flow.jpg) of the security API, I shouldn't be to far from the solution.